# Need 2 iframes on a page - 1 for menu and 1 for 100% width and height of remaining page?

Tags: html, iframe

I have been trying to sort this double iframe at 100% so that it works on desktop and iphone etc - it nearly works, but the iframe holding the gallery section refuses to be 100% height, whatever I try to do:

http://willhutchinson.co.uk/pf-test/pages/pages-overview/paul-farrell-jessie-iframe.html

I've tried a bunch of solutions and am sure it must be simple - the top iframe works, but the bottom one doesn't.

Any ideas welcome!
Cheers
Will

Comment: This is not about `java`, I removed that tag

Comment: Curious as to why you want to use iframes? Seems like you are making things more difficult by doing so (ie. clicking in the menu iframe loads new content in it) - perhaps there is a good reason you are doing so of course :) Your problem likely lies in the fact that the element the iframe is a child of (<body> in this case) has no explicit height defined so setting a height value as a percentage on the iframe will not work.

Comment: Sorry yeah - as explained below - I tried various other options. I need the gallery section to work as a resizing element and for some reason, getting something as simple as a menu above to work at the same time was proving very difficult. The menu in an iframe works brilliantly on a phone, so was trying to iframe the lot. Obviously - I would change the links to open in the parent - forgot on my test...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jQuery to solve this problem? You can get window height then if you know height of your menu iframe subtract its height from window height and set result to the iframe height?

Comment: Hi - yeah - tried a few things, but the jquery stuff controlling the flexslider gallery section seemed to be conflicting. I managed to make a massive mess, but thanks for your advice..

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help but I changed this 50% to 100% and when I decrease the size the scroll appears

```
<iframe style="position: relative; width: 50%" id="menu" src="menu.html" name="menu" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize">
```

```
<iframe style="position: relative; width: 100%" id="menu" src="menu.html" name="menu" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize">
```

Now for the images change from:

```
<iframe style="position: relative; width: 100%;" id="paul-farrell-jessie-main" src="paul-farrell-jessie-main.html" name="paul-farrell-jessie-main" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize">
```

to:

```
<iframe style="position: relative; width: 1024px; height:768px" id="paul-farrell-jessie-main" src="paul-farrell-jessie-main.html" name="paul-farrell-jessie-main" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize">
```

To make it work on mobile too you can use this:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
     /*You put css in here as you would outside but specific for the size*/
     #paul-farrell-jessie-main {
         width: 200px;
     }
}
```

To see all the options yoou have check out number 4 http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: Thanks! I will get testing.